# Facebook SDK Hash Keys, help me understand it

Tags: android, facebook, hash

I'm developing an app and it requires login via facebook.

I generated hash key through code like this:

```
try {
PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("mypackagename", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
    md.update(signature.toByteArray());
    Log.e("MY KEY HASH:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
}
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

}
```

And then I added that hash key to facebook app dashboard.

So everything worked and works on my phone but on other phone it says that another key is not stored anywhere (indeed that key is different from the one I am using).

I've read a bit about debug/release keys. My app is currently in development so I am using debug (I think) but how can it be different on different phones?

1) How do I get key that will work everytime in debug?

2) How do I get key that will work everytime in release when I export signed .APK and update my app on google play store?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1) How do I get key that will work everytime in debug?

- When using facebook if you have the same package for your app you would have the same KEY. You must type it at `Facebook Developer Console` and your would get facebook `API_KEY` and `SECRET_KEY` that you can save to strings and use then all the time when need to iteract with Facebook or other services(Such as Google Services ect.)

2) How do I get key that will work everytime in release when I export signed .APK and update my app on google play store?

- Once more, this key is the same if you use the same package and build type. But there are some tricky moments if you have many build flavors, you need to generate and save keys for production and debug for example.

Comment: Alright, but how come I got the error saying 'hashkey' is not stored anywhere? I had it stored previously it was just different and now I have 2 hash keys stored on facebook developer console? Thanks for your time